# az acr run: error: unrecognized argument: --cmd

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli, acr

I'm following the directions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli) to create a Docker image in Azure Container Registry. Everything works as expected until I get to the "Run the image" step. When I run the command:

```sh
az acr run --registry {the name of my registry} --cmd '{the name of my registry}.azurecr.io/sample/hello-world:v1" /dev/null
```

I get the following error:

```sh
az acr run: error: unrecognized argument: --cmd {the name of my registry}.azurecr.io/sample/hello-world:v1
usage: az acr run [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                  [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}]
                  [--query JMESPATH] --registry REGISTRY_NAME [--file FILE]
                  [--values VALUES] [--set SET_VALUE]
                  [--set-secret SET_SECRET] [--no-format] [--no-logs]
                  [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME]
                  [--os OS_TYPE] [--platform PLATFORM]
                  [--auth-mode {None,Default}] [--no-wait]
                  [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
                  <SOURCE_LOCATION>
```

It seems like the --cmd argument specified in the documentation is not supported by the az acr run command.

When I run az --version, I get the following:

```sh
azure-cli                         2.0.61 *
acr                                2.2.3 *
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the documentation correct? Is there a different version of the Azure CLI I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I am running an old version of the Azure CLI in the Ubuntu WSL installation on my computer. When I tried the command from the Azure Cloud Shell, which has version 2.9.1 of the Azure CLI installed, the command succeeds. Further, if I get the help for the command, I get the following, which includes the --cmd argument.

```sh
usage: az acr run [-h] [--verbose] [--debug] [--only-show-errors]
                  [--output {json,jsonc,yaml,yamlc,table,tsv,none}]
                  [--query JMESPATH] [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION] --registry
                  REGISTRY_NAME [--agent-pool AGENT_POOL_NAME] [--file FILE]
                  [--values VALUES] [--set SET_VALUE]
                  [--set-secret SET_SECRET] [--cmd CMD_VALUE] [--no-format]
                  [--no-logs] [--timeout TIMEOUT]
                  [--resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME] [--platform PLATFORM]
                  [--auth-mode {None,Default}] [--no-wait]
                  <SOURCE_LOCATION>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there is a typo at the end of the `cmd` commands with inclucing the double quotation marks ( `"` )

```
 --cmd '{the name of my registry}.azurecr.io/sample/hello-world:v1"
```

Please change it to a single quotation mark.

```
 --cmd '{the name of my registry}.azurecr.io/sample/hello-world:v1'
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I made a mistake when editing my questions.